# Backup-strategy for redundant data in postgresql-db.

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a (postgresql-9.3)-table that contains images as a bytea-column as well as several other columns that contain extracted information from these images. (Some feature points, descriptors). These values are currently stored in the DB because they are computationally rather expensive, so that I want to cache them in the DB.

However, I do not want to integrate these columns in the backup (or the WAL files) as they are rather large. Is there a way to do this or should I rather try another approach (as e.g. writing the additional data to the filesystem)?

Comment: Depending on how your DB structure looks like, you may want to add one or more `-n your_schema` to your `pg_dump` command line - this excludes blobs (see the [doc for the `-b` option](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html)).  Alternatively, if there is no further dependency on this table, you may exclude it from the dump first with `-T`, and dump it with `-t` separately (again excluding the blobs).

Comment: Don't use the DB as a cache, better use a real cache like Redis and attach foreign tables through a foreign data wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use materialized views. The main downside there is that at present there's no support for incremental refresh, so refreshing the views would be quite expensive.

Instead I suggest using `UNLOGGED` tables. That'll skip WAL archiving (and streaming replication) of the data. If you pass `--no-unlogged-table-data` it'll also omit their contents from database dumps. So you'll basically be implementing your own incrementally updated materialized views over the data.

Comment: As the computation is not done within the DB, a materialized won't work for me as I need to write into the table from the outside, but it's an interesting concept. I think I'll go with the UNLOGGED tables. Thanks!